# I have kudos in Catalyst/ideascale, why can't I give it?

Tags: catalyst

When I try to give Kudos to a proposal, it says that I don't have enough.  Even when I have kudos showing as available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are more team members in the proposal that you have, then you cannot give kudos to the proposal.
You must accumulate as many kudos as there are team members in the proposal.